# TSQL Inserting records and track ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to insert records in a table below (structure of table with example data). I have to use TSQL to achieve this:

```
MasterCategoryID    MasterCategoryDesc  SubCategoryDesc     SubCategoryID
1                   Housing             Elderly              4 
1                   Housing             Adult                5  
1                   Housing             Child                6
2                   Car                 Engine               7
2                   Car                 Engine               7
2                   Car                 Window               8
3                   Shop                owner                9
```

So for example if I enter in a new record with `MasterCategoryDesc` = 'Town' it will insert '4' in `MasterCategoryID` with the respective `SubCategoryDesc + ID`.

CAN I SIMPLIFY THIS QUESTION BY REMOVING THE SubCategoryDesc and SubCategoryID columns. How can I achieve this now just with the 2 columns MasterCategoryID and MasterCategoryDesc

Comment: Thanks Luv - was trying to figure out how to style it.

Comment: what is the actual primary key here? and why repeated rows for car/engine? And this should be 2 tables anyway

Comment: Here's the documentation for the T-SQL INSERT command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: There is no primary key, the table is structured for a cube hence repeats in mastercategoryid. I need to add more records to it.

Comment: Obviously I know how to insert records in table but how do you maintain the IDs - the mastercategoryid is incremented only if mastercategorydesc is new (does not exist/is not repeated).

Comment: Did you design the table? Then you have the solution, what to increment when, in your head. Otherwise, talke to the DBA.

Comment: No I have not designed the table. Cannot find how the table was originally populated with data. I need to add to it some more rows. I would assume you can use scope_identity OR a variable to keep track of the mastercategoryid and then do a case to see if exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT into Table1
([MasterCategoryID], [MasterCategoryDesc], [SubCategoryDesc], [SubCategoryID])
select TOP 1
    case when 'Town' not in (select [MasterCategoryDesc] from Table1) 
        then (select max([MasterCategoryID])+1 from Table1)
        else (select [MasterCategoryID] from Table1 where  [MasterCategoryDesc]='Town') 
    end as [MasterCategoryID]
    ,'Town' as [MasterCategoryDesc]
    ,'owner' as [SubCategoryDesc]
    ,case when 'owner' not in (select [SubCategoryDesc] from Table1) 
        then (select max([SubCategoryID])+1 from Table1)
        else (select [SubCategoryID] from Table1 where  [SubCategoryDesc]='owner') 
    end as [SubCategoryID]
from Table1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7415/2)**

If you want i can create a SP too. But you said you want an `T-SQL`

Comment: You need some locking hints to prevent duplicated data due to concurrency, or you need to discuss constraints that prevent duplicates and the errors that will have to be trapped and recovered from.

Comment: Thanks Luv, Please can you help me by creating it in SP (stored procedure). Also i will be reading the values from another table so can the above be automated. for example the above value 'town' will be in a variable and each time a new record is inserted the variable will also change. thanks

Comment: @MohNajdawi **[Check the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234194/insert-rows-in-table-while-maintaining-ids/17234993#17234993)**

Answer (score 0):

This will take three steps, preferably in a single Stored Procedure. Make sure it's within a transaction.

a) Check if the MasterCategoryDesc you are trying to insert already exists. If so, take its ID. If not, find the highest MasterCategoryID, increase by one, and save it to a variable.

b) The same with SubCategoryDesc and SubCategoryID.

c) Insert the new record with the two variables you created in steps a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for the `MasterCategory` and a table for the `SubCategory`. Make an `___ID` column for each one that is `identity (1,1)`. When loading, insert new rows for nonexistent values and then look up existing values for the `INSERT`.

Messing around with finding the Max and looking up data in the existing table is, in my opinion, a recipe for failure.